# Tkinter anchor left on gridbox

Tags: python, tkinter

I have packaged a group a widgets into a single widget as follows:

```py
class RunOptions(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master, bg='green')

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text='Options:')

        self.folder_button_label = tk.Label(self, text='Select a Folder', bg='white')
        self.folder_button = tk.Button(self, text='Select Image Folder')

        self.template_button = tk.Button(self, text='Select Template')
        self.template_frame = ImageCanvas(self, height=64, width=64)


        self.label.grid(row=0, sticky='W')
        self.folder_button.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='W')
        self.folder_button_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='W')
        self.template_button.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='W')
        self.template_frame.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='W')
```

and

```py
class DetectionCanvas(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.xml_var = tk.IntVar()
        self.detectframe = ImageCanvas(self, label='Detection:', height=175, width=175)
        self.x_out = tk.Label(self, bg='white', text='X:', anchor='w')
        self.y_out = tk.Label(self, bg='white', text='Y:', anchor='w')
        self.w_out = tk.Label(self, bg='white', text='W:', anchor='w')
        self.h_out = tk.Label(self, bg='white', text='H:', anchor='w')
        self.xml_check = tk.Checkbutton(self, text=' Save XML File',variable=self.xml_var)

        self.detectframe.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=4)
        self.x_out.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.y_out.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.w_out.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.h_out.grid(row=3, column=1)
        self.xml_check.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='w')
    def display_out(self, *args):
        pass
```

both of these widgets are all arranged in a large empty canvas (purple) using grid, but that doesn't matter here because the issue is in the individual widgets themselves:

[image: The two widgets are on the right side]

**I want the buttons in the options to anchor to the left, filling in the gap between the label**. For the detection widget **I want the labels to anchor left towards the canvas.** I've tried anchoring and using sticky but nothing in the second column seems to move.

Comment: Your code references `ImageCanvas` twice but doesn't provide an implementation.  You provide two other classes that don't seem to be used at all. Please [edit] your question to have a [mcve]. Since it doesn't seem like `ImageCanvas` is related to the problem (other than the fact that it's wide), it can be replaced with a labelframe or frame or canvas or something.

Comment: You're right image canvas is not related to the question. It is simply a Frame made of a label on top of a canvas widget.